# How can I get td contents with tags in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my scenario, I want to get the `td` children tags and content in the `tr` tags. I'm able to get the content but not the tags, since there are too much elements inside.

The return should be:

1. The `p` tag with it's content
2. The `table` element

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <td>
        <!-- first element -->
            <p> MY TEXT </p>
        <!-- end element -->
        </td>

        <td>
        <!-- second element -->
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <!-- end element -->
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <!-- first element -->
            <p> MY TEXT </p>
        <!-- end element -->
        </td>
        <td>
        <!-- second element -->
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p> MY TEXT </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <!-- end element -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print("The <p> tag with it's content:")
print(soup.find_all('p'))
print("\nThe <table> element:")
print(soup.find('table').prettify())
```

Output:

```
The <p> tag with it's content:
[<p> MY TEXT </p>, <p> MY TEXT </p>, <p> MY TEXT </p>, <p> MY TEXT </p>]

The <table> element:
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- first element -->
   <p>
    MY TEXT
   </p>
   <!-- end element -->
  </td>
  <td>
   <!-- second element -->
   <table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <p>
        MY TEXT
       </p>
      </td>
      <td>
       <p>
        MY TEXT
       </p>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <p>
        MY TEXT
       </p>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!-- end element -->
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```